How to digitally detect resonance in induction heater circuit?
System description: 
H-bridge network of IGBTs (inverter) is used to supply power to a parallel LC circuit connected through matching inductor. It is desired to drive the parallel LC circuit in resonance and continue tracking the resonance by implementing a close-loop digital control for this system. The expected range of resonant frequency is 10 to 100 kHz.
Proposed approach:

Obtain waveforms for current (using a CT) and voltage (using a PT) at the output of the inverter
Pass these waveforms through op-amps to obtains square waveforms
Pass waveforms from the op-amps to an XOR gate to obtain output proportional to phase difference
Pass output of XOR gate through low-pass filter and sample with ADC
Based on the ADC value, provide PWM to inverter

Query: 
Given the expected range of resonant frequency (10 to 100 kHz), what methods can be employed for detecting presence of resonance, by providing an alternate measure such as power factor, or real and apparent power?

I assume you're speaking of a circuit like so:

Consider the impedance seen by the inverter, Z.  Or, actually this was plotted as current, so 1/Z:

At high frequencies, current starts at the origin (matching inductor dominates, phase is inductive, current is small).  As frequency is swept down, approaching resonance, real current begins to rise.  The voltage phase shift between inverter and tank decreases, from 180° well above resonance, to 90° near resonance, and to 0° below resonance.  There is a point of maximum real power output, and may be zero, one or two points where inverter power factor goes to unity, or even becomes capacitive.  Below resonance, the circuit approximates an inductor divider, current rises proportional to frequency, and phase shift approaches 0°.
Note that, depending on relative values of Lm, Lw, R and C, this loop may shift vertically (for \$L_M \omega_0 \gg Z_0 Q\$, it doesn't cross the real axis at all, only the single point at \$\omega \rightarrow \infty\$ touches), and the size (width/height) of the loop, and span of frequency across the loop, all depend on exact values.
We can consider three definitions of resonance for the LLC network: 90° phase shift, peak power/voltage, and zero imaginary inverter current.  In general, these three points will not coincide, so it is important to make the right choice.
Generally, the 90° point is close enough to the peak power point, that we aren't concerned about it, or that we can choose a phase somewhat earlier to be sure we include the peak power point.
A control scheme based around this would not use inverter current, but merely tank voltage (a potential transformer, or resistor or capacitor divider, will suffice here), and perhaps if the propagation delay between control (pulse source) and inverter output is too large and drifty, inverter output voltage can be used as timing reference.
A complete control of course needs to know inverter current for limiting/protection purposes, and perhaps measuring power (but, doing measurement at-frequency is tricky, and might be better measured as DC input while approximating inverter efficiency), but as inverter current peaks then drops, and phase varies with conditions, it cannot be used as the sole control variable in a system.
The way I've done it is, as a MISO control with multiple error amps and thresholds; one each for phase, inverter current (if limiting), output voltage, power, and the output argument is max of all error amps, fed to a VCO (voltage-controlled oscillator), so the output represents driven frequency.  The frequency range of course shall be clamped to the specified range, and preferably F_min is set a little below minimum expected resonance for the given setup, to prevent phase from falling through, in case the control advances through resonance too quickly to lock onto it first.
Your suggested approach, with an XOR (type 1) phase detector, is reasonable; the missing part is you need the voltage transfer function, which has a simple (sigmoidal) phase response and therefore is a one-to-one control without latching behavior (as long as there's enough signal to detect, that is).  Whereas the current transfer function has no characteristic points that a phase detector is useful for.
Alternately, if changing topology is an option, I would encourage series resonance, and in that case inverter current is straightforward; a type 2 phase detector is required as phase is ±90° then.
Further ideas:
I don't think a current-mode control (chained/cascaded error amps) matters here, as the dominant pole of the tank response is about the same with respect to any variables.  A wired-OR structure is fine, preferably with integrator windup prevention (easy enough to implement digitally).
If you're instead doing a fixed-frequency drive, and varying supply voltage, then of course you only need the PLL, and control is a simple buck (or whatever) converter, with the dominant load response being a repeated pole at Fo / Q.

Your answer is correct and good. However, in induction heaters using parallel tank circuit, a separate inductor is used in series with the output before the tank circuit. This additional inductor changes things a bit. The OP didn't mention an additional inductor and is likely doesn't know about the additional inductor.

The additional inductor causes the inverter output to behave like a current source (pseudo current source) rather than a voltage source.

"to a parallel LC circuit connected through matching inductor" -- but a schematic would be worth showing for clarity.
